# ShellExecute с разным количеством параметров

Tags: delphi, winapi

В Delphi 10.2 пользуюсь функцией `ShellExecute` API с 6-ю параметрами
(http://kbyte.ru/ru/Programming/Guides.aspx?id=193&mode=show)
а вот наткнулся на ту же функцию `ShellExecute` API, но уже с 5-ю параметрами
(https://autoit-script.ru/autoit3_docs/functions/ShellExecute.htm)

Что это за функция такая? обе же API вроде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По второй ссылке - функция-обёртка для autoit, которая вызывает функцию `ShellExecute` из WinAPI и передаёт ей параметры (все 6). И поскольку это обёртка, то в ней некоторые параметры можно опускать, а первый параметр вообще отсутствует.

Описание же функции следует смотреть в [доках на сайте производителя](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea), а не чёрти-где:

```
HINSTANCE ShellExecuteA(
  HWND   hwnd,
  LPCSTR lpOperation,
  LPCSTR lpFile,
  LPCSTR lpParameters,
  LPCSTR lpDirectory,
  INT    nShowCmd
);
```

Comment: Я там уже смотрел, по ссылке которую вы написали просто наткнулся на функцию с 5-ю параметрами и подумал, что я чего-то не понял...

Comment: Только для Delphi 10.2 правильная ссылка на описание функции - [вот эта](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew), т.к. unicode.